# Parsing Apache CSV like string into objects

Tags: java, apache, parsing, csv, httpclient

I'm trying to parse data obtained via Apache HTTPClient in the fastest and most efficient way possible.

The data returned by the response is a string but in a CSV like format:

e.g. the String looks like this:

```
date, price, status, ...

2014-02-05, 102.22, OK,...
2014-02-05, NULL, OK
```

I thought about taking the string and manually parsing it, but this may be too slow as I have to do this for multiple requests.

Also the data returned is about 23,000 lines from one source and I may have to parse potentially several sources.

I'm also storing the data in a hash map of type:

```
Map<String, Map<String, MyObject>>
```

where the key is the source name, and value is a map with the parsed objects as a key.

So I have 2 questions, best way to parse a 23,000 line file into objects, and best way to store it.

I tried a csv parser, however the double's if not present are stored as NULL and not 0 so I will need to manually parse it.

Thanks

Comment: This is an opinion question, but my $0.02 worth is: 1) Parse it by reading in each line and splitting on the comma.  It's really the only way to do that.  Alternatively, use a pre-build lib or utility to do it for you, but those usually are not as fast due to the fact they have to be more "generic" in nature, so more code.  2) I would use a DB, rather traditional relational or one of the NoSql DBs like MongoDB.  If speed is what you are after, and you are not concerned with memory footprint, consider an in-memory DB.  This way you have the power of a query language to get stuff out.

Comment: Thanks I will stick with option one then. Storing data in the database is not so feasible for me. Does anyone have more suggestions?

Comment: Long-term storage or just data type to do lookups?  If former, why not store it in the same CSV format.  That way you can use the same parser.  If latter, depends on how you are using the data.  I'd say use a "domain" object to store each "record", I.E. CSV line, then use a Map with the key being whatever the natural primary key of the records is.

Comment: Well the data comes from an external source so the format is not really in my control unless I save it and then transform it. The data is updated daily and does nt need to be persisted, i.e only show the data for that day.

Is it ok to have a map where the value is another map with upto 23k objects. e.g. there could be like 10 keys all of which may contain thousands of objects.

Comment: My question was more about what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to solve the issue of remembering/caching a bunch of data?  Is memory footprint more of a concern or performance of lookups?  Does data persist long-term?  Are you trying to minimize the reads from the original source?  Do you have complex searching needs, or is it a simple primary key type lookup?  These all have a baring on what the answer might be.  To answer your last question, though, you can have Maps of Maps of Lists of Sets of Maps.  The level of Collection inception is limited only by your resources (memory)

Comment: No this particular data does not persist long term. I was more interested in reducing the time taken for obtaining the data and decreasing the initial start up time of the program as everything is loaded and cached before the program is actually usable. I was also not sure if the way I was parsing the data into a large Map was efficient or not, as I pass in the Map to various classes, but this should n't be much of an issue due to object referencing.

Basically the data obtained from the source is used to enrich/add to data which is persistent in a database.

Comment: The fastest way to process text data from a file is straight-up substringing.  The next fastest would be simple splits.  The issue with CSV data is that neither of these are technically viable, as a CSV file might have variable length fields (can't substring on set bounds) and might have commas within escaped fields (can't simply split on comma).  If you KNOW your input data will never fall in the second scenario, I'd say use `String`'s `split()` function.  `Map`s will be the best for quick lookups.  For speed, you might want to look into a singleton DAO with caching for reading this in.

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead with this approach.